# Catalytic poison in Pt catalysed manufacture of H2SO4

Tags: catalysis

I came across a question that goes as:

> In manufacturing of sulfuric acid in presence of platinum catalyst, which metal impurity acts as a catalytic poison?
>
> 1. Fe
> 2. Cr
> 3. Cu
> 4. V

I searched everywhere I could but did not find anything that talks about this.
I read about $\ce{As2O3}$ being a catalytic poison in this reaction and recommendations for using the Contact process using $\ce{V2O5}$ instead of this reaction.

I can understand that this is more of a fact based question but reasons or explanation (if any) should please be included.

Answer (score -1):

$\ce{Fe}$ and $\ce{V}$ are used in the contact process.
$\ce{Cu}$ is used in the preparation of chlorine gas.
Thus $\ce{Cr}$ can be used as a catalyst poison.

Comment: The question specifically asks for more explanation and/or reasons. It is best to avoid writing one line answers in such cases. Please comply by expanding your answer. Kindly also consider good formatting in future posts, it makes them more readable! -[From Review](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/99389)